# Does Ruby support conditional regular expressions

Tags: python, ruby, regex, conditional-statements

Just a language feature question, I know there's plenty of ways to do this outside of regexes (or with multiple regexes).

Does ruby support [conditional regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(%3f(condition)yes-pattern%7cno-pattern))?  Basically, an IF-THEN-ELSE branch inside a regular expression, where the predicate for the IF is the presence (or absense) of a captured group in the expression.

In perl, the syntax is `(?(predicate)yes-pattern|no-pattern)` as in

```
/(?:y|(x))(?(1)y|x)/
```

I haven't been able to find any reference to anything like it in any ruby docs that I've browsed, but I figured I'd ask here to make sure, in case I was searching for the wrong words, or it was elided from the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ruby does not support that (neither in 1.8 nor 1.9).

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, Python started to support this starting in 2.4:
http://docs.python.org/library/re#regular-expression-syntax