# Is there any way to shorten this regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match strings in the format of `A0123456`, `E0123456`, or `IN:A0123456Q`, etc. I originally made this regex

`^(IN:)?[AE][0-9]{7}Q?$`

but it was matching `IN:E012346` without the `Q` at the end. So I created this regex

`(^IN:[AE][0-9]{7}Q$)|(^[AE][0-9]{7}$)`

Is there any way to shorten this regex so that it requires both `IN:` and `Q` if they are present, but not if neither are present?

Edit: The regex will be used in Ruby.

Edit 2: I changed the regex to reflect that I was matching the wrong strings, as it would still match `IN:A0123456`.

Edit 3: Both answers below are valid, but since I am using `Ruby 2.0` and prefer a regex expression I can use in case I change my application and don't want to use the Ruby flavor of subexpression calls, I chose to accept `matt`'s answer.

Comment: Yeah, it'd probably get more complicated than it needs to be... I'd keep it like this

Comment: I edited your question to include the `ruby` tag (from your comment, now deleted)

Comment: @BartoszKP: Read the question again. It will match the case that OP wants to reject.

Comment: Whoops. You're right, sorry.

Comment: Not familiar with ruby but, that looks like an egrep expression with the pipe in the middle - does it work like egrep i.e. will match against any of the expressions delimited by pipe? If that's the case then your ^ and $ don't make sense... you'd need ^...$ | ^...$ on both expressions

Comment: FWIW Ruby [doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2208071) [support regex conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), see [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/mXW9FnOrlo). In PCRE you would use [something like](http://regex101.com/r/zR0fW0) `^(IN:)?[AE][0-9]{7}(?(1)Q)$`

Comment: @HamZa Ruby 2.0 has support for conditionals, but earlier versions don’t (and it’s not documented as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 2.0, you can use an [if-then-else conditional match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) (undocumented in the Ruby docs, but does exist):

```
/^(IN:)?[AE][0-9]{7}(?(1)Q|)$/
```

The conditional part is `(?(1)Q|)` which says if group number 1 matched, then match `Q`, else match nothing. Since group number 1 is `(IN:)`, this achieves what you want.

Comment: @nhahtdh Me too, it looks like this is new in 2.0. I’ll update answer to make that clear.

Comment: I found some docs here: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/RE. It looks like the conditional regex currently only supports [checking whether capturing groups matched](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/Onigmo-5.13.5/doc/RE#L287-299).

Answer (score 5):

The second regex has problem:

```
^(IN:[AE][0-9]{7}Q)|([AE][0-9]{7})$
```

The `|` has lower precedence than concatenation, so the regex will be parsed as:

```
^(IN:[AE][0-9]{7}Q)        # Starts with (IN:[AE][0-9]{7}Q)
|                          # OR
([AE][0-9]{7})$            # Ends with ([AE][0-9]{7})
```

To fix this problem, just use a *non-capturing group*:

```
^(?:(IN:[AE][0-9]{7}Q)|([AE][0-9]{7}))$
```

It makes sure the input string matches either format, not just starting or ending with certain format (which is clearly incorrect).

---

Regarding shortening the regex, you may replace `[0-9]` with `\d` if you want to, but it is fine as it is.

<s>I don't think there is any other way to shorten the regex within the default level of support of Ruby.</s>

#### Subroutine call

Just for your information, in Perl/PCRE, you can shorten it with ***subroutine call***:

```
^(?:([AE][0-9]{7})|(IN:(?1)Q))$
```

`(?1)` refers to the pattern defined by the first capturing group, i.e. `[AE][0-9]{7}`. The regex is effectively the same, just look shorter. [This demo](http://regex101.com/r/gF4pY2) with input `IN:E0123463Q` shows the whole text being captured by group 2 (and no text captured for group 1).

---

In Ruby, a [similar concept](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#label-Subexpression+Calls) ***subexpression call*** exists, with slightly different syntax. Ruby uses `\g<name>` or `\g<number>` to refer to the capturing group whose pattern we want to reuse:

```
^(?:([AE][0-9]{7})|(IN:\g<1>Q))$
```

The [test case here on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/GylkNad63K) under Ruby 1.9.7, for input `IN:E0123463Q`, returns `E0123463` as match for group 1 and `IN:E0123463Q` as match for group 2.

Ruby's (1.9.7) implementation seems to record the captured text for group 1 even when group 1 is not directly involved in the matching. In PCRE, *subroutine calls* does not capture text.

#### Conditional regex

There is also ***conditional regex*** that allows you to check whether a certain capturing group matches something or not. You can check [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752663/1400768) for more information.

Comment: Does `Ruby`'s subexpression call work in other regular expression implementations?